# How to add (or suggest) a tag to an existing question?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I've encountered several questions that are tagged to broadly, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224406/the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype) is specific to sql-server, maybe even to sql-server 2008 yet it is tagged just "sql".

Other questions on this site suggest the original author to edit his/her own question.  But I can't find how to do this for another user's question.  Is this a privilege for which I still have to earn sufficient reputation?

What is the recommended way to add a tag to such a question?

Comment: You can edit any post on Stack Overflow - if you don't have enough reputation it will simply need to be reviewed first.

Comment: check question again i have retaged it, it require 500+ repo to add tag without any permissions, it will not give any repo at aal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always edit it and add the tag--just that you'r edit will be added to the suggested queue, and until it is reviewed, it's only visible to you.

Whenever you put something in the edit queue, try to improve it as much as possible. Since others have to waste time reviewing it, it's always better to add as many improvements as possible. Aside from retagging, you can check grammar, reformat, and clarify stuff.

[At 500 rep, you get the ability to retag questions without having it queued](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)

[At 2000, you can edit as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)

Note that you lose the ability to get +2 on retag/edit once you get the ability to independently do those actions.